# PHP contact form not working

Tags: php, forms, contacts

My php contact form will send me to the thank you page as if it its going to send but never sends me the mail this is the contact form code

```
<div id="ContactMe">
<h2 class="ContactMe">Contact</h2>
    <div class="contact">
<p>Well you say you are interested in contacting me. You came to the right place. You have several options in this case. Feel free to fill out the form or just message me on social media. </p>
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12"> 
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="row moveMe3">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                 <form name="sentMessage" class="well" id="contactForm"  action="process.php">
           <h2>Contact Me</h2>
           <br />
         <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                   placeholder="Full Name Required" id="name" required
                       data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name" />
              <p class="help-block"></p>
           </div>
             </div>     
                <div class="control-group">
                  <div class="controls">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Required" 
                            id="email" required
                       data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email" />
                       <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
        </div>  

               <div class="control-group">
                 <div class="controls">
                 <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" 
                       placeholder="Message"  required
               data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message" 
                       data-validation-minlength-message="Min 5 characters" 
                        maxlength="999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
        </div>
               </div>        
         <div id="success"> </div><br /> <!-- For success/fail messages -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send</button><br />
          </form>
    </div>
```

this is the other files that go along with it 
process.php

```
<?php
// check if fields passed are empty
  if (empty($_POST["name"]))
    {$nameErr = "Name is required";}
  else
    {$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);}

  if (empty($_POST["email"]))
    {$emailErr = "Email is required";}
  else
    {$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);}

  if (empty($_POST["comment"]))
    {$comment = "";}
  else
    {$comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);}





$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// create email body and send it    
$to = 'preshesgirl@yahoo.com'; 
$email_subject = "Contact form submitted by:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. \n\n".
                  " Here are the details:\n \nName: $name \n ".
                  "Email: $email_address\n Message \n $message";
$headers = "From: preshesgirl@yahoo.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//return true;
//redirect to the 'thank you' page

header('Location: thankyou.php');


?>
thank you.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Thank you</title>

    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
<link href="./css/base.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div id="response"></div> 
        <div class="contactus" id="moveMe2">
             <p class="contatMessage"> Thank you for contacting me I will get back with you as soon as possible.</p>
             <img src="./images/thankyou.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

contact form.php

```
<?php
if (session_id() == '') session_start();
/*******************************************************************************
*  Title: Easy PHP Contact Form (Captcha Version)
*  Version: 2.1 @ October 17, 2011
*  Author: Vishal P. Rao
*  Website: http://www.easyphpcontactform.com
********************************************************************************
*  COPYRIGHT NOTICE
*  Copyright 2010 Vishal P. Rao. All Rights Reserved.
*
*  This script may be used and modified free of charge by anyone
*  AS LONG AS COPYRIGHT NOTICES AND ALL THE COMMENTS REMAIN INTACT.
*  By using this code you agree to indemnify Vishal P. Rao or 
*  www.easyphpcontactform.com from any liability that might arise from 
*  it's use.
*
*  Selling the code for this program, in part or full, without prior
*  written consent is expressly forbidden.
*
*  Obtain permission before redistributing this software over the Internet
*  or in any other medium. In all cases copyright and header must remain
*  intact. This Copyright is in full effect in any country that has
*  International Trade Agreements with the India
*
*  Removing any of the copyright notices without purchasing a license
*  is illegal! 
*******************************************************************************/

/*******************************************************************************
 *  Script configuration - Refer README.txt
*******************************************************************************/

require "formfiles/contact-config.php";

$error_message = '';

if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  showForm();

} else { //form submitted

  $error = 0;

  if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $name[2] = clean_var($_POST['name']);
  }
  else {
    $error = 1;
    $name[3] = 'color:#FF0000;';
  }

  if(!empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email[2] = clean_var($_POST['email']);
    if (!validEmail($email[2])) {
      $error = 1;
      $email[3] = 'color:#FF0000;';
      $email[4] = '<strong><span style="color:#FF0000;">Invalid email</span></strong>';
      }
  }
  else {
    $error = 1;
    $email[3] = 'color:#FF0000;';
  }

  if(!empty($_POST['subject'])) {
    $subject[2] = clean_var($_POST['subject']);
    if (function_exists('htmlspecialchars')) $subject[2] = htmlspecialchars($subject[2], ENT_QUOTES);   
  }
  else {
    $error = 1;
    $subject[3] = 'color:#FF0000;';
  }  

  if(!empty($_POST['message'])) {
    $message[2] = clean_var($_POST['message']);
    if (function_exists('htmlspecialchars')) $message[2] = htmlspecialchars($message[2], ENT_QUOTES);
  }
  else {
    $error = 1;
    $message[3] = 'color:#FF0000;';
  }    

  if(empty($_POST['captcha_code'])) {
    $error = 1;
    $code[3] = 'color:#FF0000;';
  } else {
    include_once "formfiles/contact-securimage.php";
        $securimage = new Securimage();
    $valid = $securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']);

    if(!$valid) {
      $error = 1;
      $code[3] = 'color:#FF0000;';   
      $code[4] = '<strong><span style="color:#FF0000;">Incorrect code</span></strong>';
    }
  }

  if ($error == 1) {
    $error_message = '<div style="font-weight:bold;font-size:90%;margin-bottom:5px;}">Please correct/enter field(s) in red.</div>';

    showForm();

  } else {

    if (function_exists('htmlspecialchars_decode')) $subject[2] = htmlspecialchars_decode($subject[2], ENT_QUOTES);
    if (function_exists('htmlspecialchars_decode')) $message[2] = htmlspecialchars_decode($message[2], ENT_QUOTES);     

    $body = "$name[0]: $name[2]\r\n\r\n";
    $body .= "$email[0]: $email[2]\r\n\r\n";
    $body .= "$message[0]:\r\n$message[2]\r\n\r\n";

    if (!$from) $from_value = $email[2];
    else $from_value = $from;

    require_once('formfiles/class.phpmailer.php');

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->SetFrom($from_value);  
    $mail->AddReplyTo($email[2]);
    $mail->Subject = "$subject_prefix - $subject[2]";
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }

    if (!$thank_you_url) {    
      if ($use_header_footer) {
                include $header_file;
                $form_width = '100%';
            }
      echo '<a name="cform"><!--Form--></a>'."\n";
      echo '<div id="formContainer" style="width: '.$form_width.';height: '.$form_height.';text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">'."\n";
      echo $GLOBALS['thank_you_message']."\n";
      echo '</div>'."\n";
      if ($use_header_footer) include $footer_file;
      }
      else {
        header("Location: $thank_you_url");
      }

      session_unset();
    session_destroy();    

  }

} //else submitted



function showForm()

{
global $name, $email, $subject, $message, $code;
global $where_included, $use_header_footer, $header_file, $footer_file;
global $form_width, $form_height, $form_background, $form_border_color, $form_border_width, $form_border_style, $cell_padding, $left_col_width;     

if ($use_header_footer) {
    include $header_file;
    $form_width = '100%';
}

echo <<<EOD
<a name="cform"><!--Form--></a>
<div id="formContainer" style="width: {$form_width};">
{$GLOBALS['error_message']}
<form method="post" id="cForm" action="{$where_included}#cform">
<table style="width:100%; height:{$form_height}; background:{$form_background}; border:{$form_border_width} {$form_border_style} {$form_border_color}; padding:10px;" id="contactForm">
<tr>
<td style="width:{$left_col_width}; text-align:left; vertical-align:top; padding:{$cell_padding}; font-weight:bold; {$name[3]}">{$name[0]}</td>
<td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:top; padding:{$cell_padding};"><input type="text" name="{$name[1]}" value="{$name[2]}" id="{$name[1]}" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:{$left_col_width}; text-align:left; vertical-align:top; padding:{$cell_padding}; font-weight:bold; {$email[3]}">{$email[0]}</td>
<td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:top; padding:{$cell_padding};"><input type="text" name="{$email[1]}" value="{$email[2]}" id="{$email[1]}" /> {$email[4]}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:{$left_col_width}; text-align:left; vertical-align:top; padding:{$cell_padding}; font-weight:bold; {$subject[3]}">{$subject[0]}</td>
<td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:top; padding:{$cell_padding};"><input type="text" name="{$subject[1]}" value="{$subject[2]}" size="40" id="{$subject[1]}" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:{$left_col_width}; text-align:left; vertical-align:top; padding:{$cell_padding}; font-weight:bold; {$message[3]}">{$message[0]}</td>
<td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:top; padding:{$cell_padding};"><textarea name="{$message[1]}" cols="40" rows="6" id="{$message[1]}">{$message[2]}</textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:{$left_col_width}; text-align:left; vertical-align:top; padding:{$cell_padding};">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:top; padding:{$cell_padding};"><img id="captcha" src="formfiles/contact-securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:{$left_col_width}; text-align:left; vertical-align:top; padding:{$cell_padding}; font-weight:bold; {$code[3]}">{$code[0]}</td>
<td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:top; padding:{$cell_padding};"><input type="text" name="{$code[1]}" size="10" maxlength="5" id="{$code[1]}" /> {$code[4]}
<br /><br />(Please enter the text in the image above. Text is not case sensitive.)<br />
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = 'formfiles/contact-securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false">Click here if you cannot recognize the code.</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; padding:{$cell_padding}; font-size:90%; font-weight:bold;">All fields are required.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; padding:{$cell_padding};"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="border:1px solid #999;background:#E4E4E4;margin-top:5px;" id="submit_button" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<!-- Removing the attribution link without obtaining a licence is illegal and prohibited -->
<!-- Check out Branding Removal option at http://www.easyphpcontactform.com/ -->
<div style="width:100%;text-align:right;font-size:80%;margin-top: 0;">
<a href="http://www.easyphpcontactform.com/" title="Easy PHP Contact Form" target="_blank">Easy PHP Contact Form</a>
</div>
</div>
EOD;

if ($use_header_footer) include $footer_file;
}

function clean_var($variable) {
    $variable = strip_tags(stripslashes(trim(rtrim($variable))));
  return $variable;
}

/**
Email validation function.
*/
function validEmail($email)
{
   $isValid = true;
   $atIndex = strrpos($email, "@");
   if (is_bool($atIndex) && !$atIndex)
   {
      $isValid = false;
   }
   else
   {
      $domain = substr($email, $atIndex+1);
      $local = substr($email, 0, $atIndex);
      $localLen = strlen($local);
      $domainLen = strlen($domain);
      if ($localLen < 1 || $localLen > 64)
      {
         // local part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255)
      {
         // domain part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($local[0] == '.' || $local[$localLen-1] == '.')
      {
         // local part starts or ends with '.'
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $local))
      {
         // local part has two consecutive dots
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain))
      {
         // character not valid in domain part
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain))
      {
         // domain part has two consecutive dots
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (!preg_match('/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\\/$\'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/', str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
      {
         // character not valid in local part unless 
         // local part is quoted
         if (!preg_match('/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/',
             str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
         {
            $isValid = false;
         }
      }
      if ($isValid && function_exists('checkdnsrr'))
      {
        if (!(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || checkdnsrr($domain,"A"))) {
         // domain not found in DNS
         $isValid = false;
       }
      }
   }
   return $isValid;
}


?>
```

send mail.php

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr =  "";
$name = $email  = $comment =  "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

  if (empty($_POST["name"]))
    {$nameErr = "Name is required";}
  else
    {$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);}

  if (empty($_POST["email"]))
    {$emailErr = "Email is required";}
  else
    {$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);}

  if (empty($_POST["comment"]))
    {$comment = "";}
  else
    {$comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);}


}
function test_input($data)
{
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
}

?>
```

my email is correct in all the spots I have already checked that.

Comment: Do you have `sendmail()` set up on your server?

Comment: The very first step would be to remove the `header` redirects and check the return value of the `mail()` function. And of course do something with the errors you are checking for...

Comment: i think it is automatically set up since I host via hostagtor

Comment: so i need to get rid of the $header all together

Answer (score 2):

You should have `sendmail` set up on your web server to send emails.

**To check/change your PHP mail configuration:**

1. Open your php.ini file (if you don't know where this is, see below)
2. Search for the line that reads [mail function]
3. Add/change the details of your mail server.
   This could be a local mail server or the mail server of your ISP.
4. Save/close the php.ini file
5. Restart your web server.

In case if you want to test it **locally**, you can do this: [Send email from localhost/WAMP Server using sendmail](http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/).

Comment: I have hostgator as my server so how would  I do that with them

Comment: You don't need to do anything with them as they already have everything set up! `:)`

Comment: that is what I thought but my form is still going to the thank you page and not sending me the email and my email is correct

Comment: You have to open a support request with HostGator! @KenaAlysPechacek

Comment: they will fix it for me im confused

Comment: They will fix it for you! You have paid them. Use their live support.